# How to display image in img ASP control?

Tags: asp.net

I want to display image in img control.

Asp code:

```
<asp:Image id="id" src='<%# Eval("Item.SmallPicPath") %>' Runat="Server" >
```

C# code:

```
      public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   Glasses item=GetItemByID(GlassesID)    //retrive record from data base
}
```

Glasses is a class that have property SmallPicPath.

I try to display image but i get error any idea how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you use for that ? repeater, gridview ? what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you're trying to use is based on databinding, which generally isn't good for a single image.

Instead, try something like this markup:

```
<asp:Image id="MyImageId" runat="server">
```

Then, in your code behind:

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Glasses item = GetItemByID(GlassesID);    //retrive record from data base
    this.MyImageId.ImageUrl = item.SmallPicPath;
}
```

If you still want to use databinding for some reason, something like this should work (although there's a performance cost compared to the other approach):

```
<asp:Image id="MyImageId" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# item.SmallPicPath %>">
```

Code-behind:

```
public Glasses item;

public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.item = GetItemByID(GlassesID);    //retrive record from data base
    this.MyImageId.DataBind();
}
```

Databinding is an optional operation; you need to call `DataBind()` on the control (or its parent) to make it happen.

You only need "Eval()" in cases that involve a data container (usually via a `DataSource`) -- which this one doesn't.

Comment: Thank you Rick.But why my approach is wrong?why cant i bind single image to control?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Image id="id" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Item.SmallPicPath") %>' Runat="Server" >
```

The Eval expression might not be Item.SmallPicPath. If your data object is type of **Glass** and this type has SmallPicPath property, then use Eval("SmallPicPath").